# Configuration for passing NGINX request to Express?

Tags: express, nginx

I'm creating a website with NGINX handling Static content, SSL and all that stuff, while my API and non-static websites are handled by Express.
Now, I'd like NGINX to pass stuff like "/update" to Express. However, I'm not sure how to configure that.

Is the example below [from DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-16-04) functional for https websites in the first place? Shouldn't I configure the same SSL certificate that NGINX uses to Express, so it redirect to https://website.com/update instead of http://website.com/update?

```
    location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the extact question. Do you want to pass request that contain /update` to express server or you want to redirect `https://website.com/update` to this http://website.com/update `

Comment: Apologies, I was a bit unclear
In essence, I simply want to pass to the express server @AjitSoman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To proxy pass any API request starting with `/update` Example: http://localhost:3000/update, http://localhost:3000/update/test etc.. You can use below nginx config inside server block:

```
location /update {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }
```

If you want to redirect http://website.com/update to https://website.com/update . You will need to create a server at 80 port which will redirect any request that come at 80 port will be redirect to https://website.com/update

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name website.com;
    return 301 https://website.com$request_uri;
}
```